# Creating a new row where values between columns are different

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to create a new row when values between two columns are different.

Data sample:

```
SELECT * FROM SOURCE_TABLE

Info   Date          Observed    Boolean
QWE    2020-03-08    2020-03-08  true
QWE    2020-03-14    2020-03-16  true         
QWE    2020-03-20    2020-03-20  false
```

I'm trying to write a statement that would make a new row when the `Date` and `Observed` columns have a different value. In the final table I'd keep only the `Date` column, without `Observed`, and have a new `Boolean_date` and `Boolean_observed` columns with true/false values.
Other columns would stay the same value (keep the value from the row where the two columns differ).

So the new result would look like this:

```
Info   Date          Observed     Boolean_date  Boolean_observed
QWE    2020-03-08    2020-03-08   true          true
QWE    2020-03-14    2020-03-16   true          false
QWE    2020-03-16    2020-03-16   false         true
QWE    2020-03-20    2020-03-20   false         false
```

In SQL Server I would use CROSS APPLY in this case, but that is not available in Snowflake.
I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
    ...
    CASE 
        WHEN Boolean = true AND "Date" = Observed THEN Boolean_date = true AND Boolean_observed = true
        WHEN Boolean = false AND "Date" = Observed THEN Boolean_date = false AND Boolean_observed = false
        WHEN Boolean = true AND "Date" <> Observed THEN (INSERT NEW ROW)

    END
FROM SOURCE_TABLE
```

If you have any other approach that would work better, please suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this exactly represents what you need, but here goes

```
with st(info, date, observed, boolean) as
(select * from values
    ('QWE','2020-03-08'::date, '2020-03-08'::date, True),
    ('QWE','2020-03-14'::date, '2020-03-16'::date, True),
    ('QWE','2020-03-20'::date, '2020-03-20'::date, False))
select
    coalesce(t0.info, t1.info) info,
    coalesce(t0.date, t1.observed) date,
    coalesce(t0.observed, t1.observed) observed,
    coalesce(t0.boolean, False) as boolean_date, 
case
    when coalesce(t0.boolean, True)
     and coalesce(t0.date, t1.observed) = coalesce(t0.observed, t1.observed) then True
    else False
end as boolean_observed
from st t0
full outer join st t1
on t0.date = t1.observed
order by 2
```

| INFO | DATE | OBSERVED | BOOLEAN_DATE | BOOLEAN_OBSERVED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QWE | 2020-03-08 | 2020-03-08 | True | True |
| QWE | 2020-03-14 | 2020-03-16 | True | False |
| QWE | 2020-03-16 | 2020-03-16 | False | True |
| QWE | 2020-03-20 | 2020-03-20 | False | False |

Comment: While this appears to work at first, it creates duplicate values for a lot of entries with different Boolean_date and Boolean_observed values. I'm not exactly sure why that happens